# uploading date to sql server database - issues with UK date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I have an excel workbook that contains some vba code. The code uploads some data to a SQL Server database.

The code runs on my computer but not on another users. My computer is set to US date time format the other users computer is set to UK date time format.

The error message is the following,

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
```

Below is a code snippet.

DateEntry & DateTemp are both columns of type "Date".

How do I fix this? Also I don't understand why there is an error as I though a date variable was actually treated as a number.

```
rs.Open SQLUPLOADTABLENAME, pCn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

iCol = 1
iRow = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(ws.Cells(iRow, iCol))
    rs.AddNew
    rs("DateEntry") = DateTime.Date
    rs("DateTemp") = pDtTemp
    rs("Temperature") = ws.cells(iRow, iCol)        
    rs.Update
    iRow = iRow + 1
Loop
```

**Update**

More info on pDtTemp. strDate is a string supplied in the format yyyymmdd

```
Private pDtTemp As Date

pDtTemp = DateTime.DateSerial(CInt(Strings.Left(strDate, 4)), CInt(Strings.Mid(strDate, 5, 2)), CInt(Strings.Right(strDate, 2)))
```

**Fixed**

I just changed the two line to the below lines & it now works. Can't say I understand completely what is going on in the background

```
    rs("DateEntry") = Format(DateTime.Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    rs("DatePrice") = Format(pDtPrice, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: How is `pDtTemp` declared and assigned?

Comment: @Rory I've just added some extra code which shows pDtTemp being declared and assigned

Comment: in MS Access I use `CLng(Date)` instead of  `DateTime.Date`.

Comment: pDtTemp is declared in this method or passed in from elsewhere? If the latter, are you passing as a string or as a date? In other words -- when you debug, what is the literal value of pDtTemp?

Comment: when debugging pDtTemp is a date and it has the value 12/01/2016

Comment: Usually I use "dd mmm yyyy" to remove any ambiguity.